# Mac OS X 10.2 Jaguar installation on iBook G4 stalls at gray screen, shows folder icon with question mark, then Finder icon, and then freezes

Tags: macos, startup, install, performance

Recently, I made a Jaguar install disc from an ISO and tried booting from it on my iBook G4 12-inch. I tried booting from Startup Manager, expecting the Apple logo to appear and the CD to boot from the installer, but I got a grey screen for a long period of time, and then I saw a folder icon with a question mark briefly, then it changed to a Finder icon, then froze, however the disc was still spinning in the drive. I tried it on my PowerBook G4 Titanium. Saw an Apple logo, but then KERNEL PANIC. Do you think these 2 computers are compatible with Mac OS X Jaguar? (according to the readme file in the disc, I believe it mentioned it was compatible with PowerBook G4 and iBook models) or did I get a corrupted copy of Jaguar?

Answer (score 1):

According to everymac.com, the earliest iBook G4 12-inch requires at least OS X 10.3. Therefore, you should not expect to boot from Jaguar (OS X 10.2).

Jaguar is compatible with some (but not all) PowerBook G4 Titanium models.